# How to check which pytest mark is the test running for

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a test file eg: test_my_api.py

And I call the pytest to start executing using below command, to run test only with specific mark

```
pipenv run pytest -m "integration"
```

Now in my test_my_api.py file I have multiple functions marked as "integration"

Also I have a global variable configured as below, and using this global value DATA in all methods

```
DATA = get_my_data()
```

Now I have another mark called "smoke", now some test cases has both the mark "smoke" and "integration". For smoke i need global data as different as below,

DATA = get_smoke_data()

The issue is while running the test case I can't split for which mark this test case is getting called . i.e for smoke or for integration. How can I get this info in global level ?

Previously I know there was something called Mark info eg: from _pytest.mark import MarkInfo but this is removed now. And this is available only inside every method How can I get it on global level

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question: what do you mean by "for which mark this test case is getting called"? Do you mean if you filter for a test, the test has to know which filter was used? Can you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: yes correct which filter this test us execution. I.e if i can mark a test case with 2 filters and while running i will specify only one filter (i.e mark) so while running I want to know for which filter this test cases is getting executed

Comment: So you want to change the behavior of the test depending on the filter it is called with? E.g. if pytest filters for `integration` one behavior, if it filters for `smoke`, and if is called without a filter, something else? That sounds to me as if you are mixing two concepts here - filtering and test configuration. I'm still not sure what do you want to achieve, maybe there is a better way?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how can I get this value? https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/historical-notes.html#marker-revamp-and-iteration.   
This says that I can use " _pytest.nodes.Node.iter_markers()" to get the markers name . But I am not sure how to use it there is no example

Comment: This is to get the markers of a test function, say, from a fixture or a plugin. This is not related to the filter you are using in pytest. Depending what you actually want to do (still don't know that), this may or may not help you.

Comment: yes exactly so when the test is running , I wanted to check what markers are active. I mean I need to see while the test is running which marker is active and based on that i can decide

Comment: Maybe you can update the question to describe why you need the filter at run-time? From the current question this is not clear (at least for me), and I still struggle to understand your use case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you trying to know which marker is called for test method having more than one marker during run time ?

Is this something you are looking for ?

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_common_fixture(request, pytestconfig):
    markers_arg = pytestconfig.getoption('-m')
    request.cls.marker_name = markers_arg


class TestSmokeIntegration:
    @pytest.mark.smoke
    @pytest.mark.integration
    def test_for_smoke_integration(self, my_common_fixture):
        print("marker used: ", self.marker_name)
        assert True

    def test_somthing_else(my_common_fixture):
        assert True
```

```
pytest -vvv -s test_marker.py -m smoke
```

output:

```
test_marker.py::TestSmokeIntegration::test_for_smoke_integration markers used:  smoke
PASSED
```

```
pytest -vvv -s test_marker.py -m integration
```

output:

```
test_marker.py::TestSmokeIntegration::test_for_smoke_integration marker used:  integration
PASSED
```

Comment: this worked well for me. just a suggestion - if you add `autouse=True` in your fixture decorator, then you dont need to pass it to your test functions as an argument.

Comment: `config.getoption('-m')` works like a champ, didn't know `-m` was considered an option but makes sense looking back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to support marker expressions, such as `-m foo OR bar` or dynamically added markers (i.e. `add_marker()`), then you may need something more elaborate:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def active_marks(request):

  # Collect all the marks for this node (test)
  current_node = request.node
  marks = []
  while current_node:
    marks += [mark.name for mark in current_node.iter_markers()]
    current_node = current_node.parent

  # Get the mark expression - what was passed to -m
  markExpr = request.config.option.markexpr

  # Compile the mark expression
  from _pytest.mark.expression import Expression
  compiledMarkExpr = Expression.compile(markExpr)

  # Return a sequence of markers that match
  return [ mark for mark in marks if compiledMarkExpr.evaluate( lambda candidate: candidate == mark ) ]


class TestClass:
  def test_foo(active_marks):
    print(f"Active marks are {active_marks}")
```